# Redis multiple tables?

Tags: redis, go-redis

I have a use case where I have to search by key and in another use case, I have to search by value. Given this scenario, what's the best approach as scanning the entire cache can degrade performance (to filter by value).

1. Do reverse store i.e store value as key and key as the value in the same logical table?
2. Use different database and store Value, Key as K | V. I see a few posts that suggest using a different database is a bad idea and deprecated?

Or is there a better alternative/approach?

Comment: Did you check https://redisearch.io?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use Redis? Redis (and generally key-value stores) are not optimized for this kind of task.

If you need to stick with Redis you can create index to implement search by value. It will not be as storage effective and intuitive as e.g. SQL database table though. See documentation here: https://redis.io/topics/indexes